# Passing argument to read function, from structures like (char *) &(struct)

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Reading K&R book ANSI, and bump into, source code that can't understand, it is about `readdir` function. That code is big. So it is like:

```
typedef struct {
  long ino;       
  char name[NAME_MAX+1];
} Dirent;
```

and in `readdir` function we have:

```
Dirent *dirbuf;
```

and NOW, there is:

```
            ignore    what is this     what is dis      what is dis
while (read(dp->fd, (char *) &dirbuf , sizeof(dirbuf) ) == sizeof( dirbuf) )
```

And "what is dis and what is this" is part of the question, please explain me what it does. I had been playing with it to check if (`char *`) search in struct for `char *` and take IT to `read` function when find, but it doesn't? Also can you explain that statement when is checking does it equal with `sizeof( dirbuf)` , and why third argument isn't `sizeof(dirbuf->name)`? Here what i tried:

```
struct lele{
    int dig;
    char name[20];

};

int main(void)
{
    struct lele p;

    scanf("%d%s", (int *) &p, (char *) &p);
    printf("name: %s ,,, dig : %d\n", p.name, p.dig);
    return 0;
}
```

```
INPUT: 5 , green

OUTPUT: name: n ,,, dig : 1701147239
```

Also can explain and OUTPUT?
**EDIT** Mainstream question is why second argument isn't `dirbuf->name` ?
Code for `readdir`:

```
#include <sys/dir.h> /* local directory structure */
/* readdir: read directory entries in sequence */
Dirent *readdir(DIR *dp)
{
     struct direct dirbuf; /* local directory structure */
     static Dirent d; /* return: portable structure */
     while (read(dp->fd, (char *) &dirbuf, sizeof(dirbuf))
        == sizeof(dirbuf)) {
      if (dirbuf.d_ino == 0) /* slot not in use */
         continue;
      d.ino = dirbuf.d_ino;
      strncpy(d.name, dirbuf.d_name, DIRSIZ);
      d.name[DIRSIZ] = '\0'; /* ensure termination */
      return &d;
}
return NULL;
}
```

Comment: too much for one question

Comment: Explain what? The code is working as it should.

Comment: Unless you have the extreme misfortune to be still using a K&R-based compiler, I would suggest getting a book that deals with the modern language that C has become, not what it looked like in its infancy...

Comment: Why is that kind output?

Comment: That section of K&R no longer works on modern versions of Unix (or, more precisely, on most modern file systems on modern versions of Unix).  You can't read a directory any more (but you could when it was written, and up to some time in the mid-90s).  That said, the code can still be explained.

Comment: The bit of the question is why arguments passed like that, sorry if i didn't mainstream section. I still reading book, because, to increment skill, work with objects.

Answer (score 1):

Back in the days of yore (or K&R), directories on a UFS (Unix File System) could be read with `open()`, `read()`, `close()`.  Further, the file names were limited to 14 characters and inode numbers were limited to 2 bytes (`unsigned short`).  And a directory consisted of 16-byte entries:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| inode | . | \0| \0| \0| \0| \0| \0| \0| \0| \0| \0| \0| \0| \0|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| inode | . | . | \0| \0| \0| \0| \0| \0| \0| \0| \0| \0| \0| \0|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| inode | f | i | l | e | n | a | m | e | \0| \0| \0| \0| \0| \0|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| inode | l | o | n | g | e | r | f | i | l | e | n | a | m | e |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 00000 | d | e | l | e | t | e | d | - | f | i | l | e | \0| \0|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| inode | o | t | h | e | r | n | a | m | e | \0| \0| \0| \0| \0|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Note that 14-character names were the max, but such names were not null-terminated.  Deleted entries had an inode number of zero but the name was not zapped.  The null padding matches what `strncpy()` does (though it is not clear that `strncpy()` was actually used to do it).

More modern file systems allow for variable length names and avoid wasting space by only allocating as much space as necessary for the name, and they use large inode numbers.

The code shown in the question is:

```
while (read(dp->fd, (char *)&dirbuf, sizeof(dirbuf)) == sizeof(dirbuf))
```

This looks like the first edition; in those days, there was no `void *` and `char *` was the universal pointer.  This executes the `read()` function call, treating the `dirbuf` variable as a buffer.  `sizeof(dirbuf)` gives the size of the variable in bytes.  So, this reads a fixed number of bytes into the variable.  The `read()` system call returns the number of bytes it read; if that was not the number requested, there was a problem — probably EOF (indicated by zero), or perhaps -1 (problems with the file descriptor), or perhaps a number less than the size requested (indicating, probably, corruption in the file system).  So, overall, the loop reads directory entries into the structure variable `dirbuf`.

I'm not convinced about the sizes shown in the structure (`long` is 4 bytes, and there was no null padding).  I'd have to look at what they're up to.